# join rows on column (microsoff SSIS)

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, ssis

I have excel file that contains these informations

```
Contry  | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 |2003
----------------------------------
Tunisia | X1   | X2   | X3   |X4
-------------------------------------
Algeria | X21  | X22  | X23  |X24
-------------------------------------
```

And I want to store these information in database like this

```
Tunisia 2000 X1
--
Tunisia 2001 X2
--
Tunisia 2002 X3
--
Tunisia 2003 X4
--
Algeria 2000 X21
--
Algeria 2001 X22
--
Algeria 2002 X23
--
Algeria 2003 X24
```

I'm using SSIS and I'm beginner with most of the components .. 
Thanks

Comment: try searching for sql-server pivot....

Comment: There's a youtube video for everything now. You actually want **unpivot**. Follow this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmCpMWQGw7M and if you have any issues, ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you have Excel 2010 or later, you can use `Power Pivot` or `Data` ► `Get and Transform` ► `From Table` to `UnPivot` those columns.  Then relabel as you wish:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can load data as it is in some temp table and then unpivot and insert in table you need:

```
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max) = '',
        @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @cols = @cols + ','+QUOTENAME(name)
FROM sys.columns
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('#temp')
AND name != 'Country'

SELECT @sql = N'
INSERT INTO NewTable
SELECT  Country,
        [Year],
        [Values]
FROM #temp
UNPIVOT (
    [Values] FOR [Year] IN ('+STUFF(@cols,1,1,'')+')
) unpvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Output of would be inserted:

```
Country Year    Values
Tunisia 2000    X1
Tunisia 2001    X2
Tunisia 2002    X3
Tunisia 2003    X4
Algeria 2000    X21
Algeria 2001    X22
Algeria 2002    X23
Algeria 2003    X24
```

Note: I use dynamic SQL because I'm not sure about number of columns (years) in your input table. If the number of columns is determined - then better load data in temp table and then use:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable
SELECT  Country,
        [Year],
        [Values]
FROM #temp
UNPIVOT (
    [Values] FOR [Year] IN ([2000],[2001],[2002],[2003])
) unpvt
```

Or one more way is to use pivoting in Excel  and load its results to destination table (`NewTable` in my example). This is shown in answer provided by @RonRosenfeld.